# Add member values to input_html of checkboxes in formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin, formtastic

How can I add member-attributes of a collection to the input_html of a formastic collection form-input (checkboxes?) I have:

```
f.input :requirements, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => @requirements, :input_html => {"data-name" => :name}
```

(Using Active-Admin)

Now I want to append a html-attribute like data-name to every checkbox. The value of this attribute depends on an attribute of the member-object (e.g. the name). So I need to evaluate an expression for every created checkbox; have also tried something with lambda and Proc.new, but this didn't work.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
= f.input :requirements, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Requirement.all.map{|r| [r.name, r.id, {'data-name' => r.name}]}
```

Comment: This approach works for me with arbitrary hash keys, but not when passing `disabled` as a key, as it seems to be getting actively removed by formtastic.